# D3 Zoom disables mousemove event in the lower layer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

After I called D3 zoom, there's a 'rect.background' overlayed on the top of svg. This prevents the mousemove event to get to my original svg.

Originally I toggled a mousemove event to the circles to enable fast browsing.

How can I get it back?

My idea is, override the 'rect.background' mousemove event and propagate the event to the back layer if the button isn't pressed.

Comment: You'll have to give us some more information than that. Where does that background element come from and how did you implement the zoom?

Comment: have you tried giving the rect.background the .attr("pointer-events", "none")? maybe it works